# .htaccess Rewrite to Force Trailing Slash at the end

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in my htaccess file:

```
# Force Trailing Slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

That seems to work fine when I go to **www.mydomain.com/test** it redirects it to /test/.  The problem is when I go to **www.mydomain.com/test/another** it doesn't put the trailing slash on another.

Does anyone know how to modify my code to make the trailing slash work no matter how long the URL is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

**Edit**: in the case you want to exclude some requests like for php files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You may also want to include css and js. This is very useful!

Comment: @undone Might I ask what the `?` after html stands for, and why you didn't put `php?` with the question mark?

Comment: @DanFromGermany question mark in regexp indicates that preceding character (in this case **l**) , may or may not exists in the string. so in can cover both **htm**  and **html**  extensions!

Answer (score 72):

A slightly more robust answer, based on [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7781331/1453062):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

The `RewriteCond` will check to make sure there's no files with that name, and if not, perform the RewriteRule. More future-proof than having a manual list of extensions!

Comment: I tried this, but it is adding a trailing slash on files that end in .html

Comment: If the URL leads to a real file, it shouldn't be hitting this rule; are you unnecessarily adding `.html` to your "nice" URLs?

Comment: Not me, but I guess Magento is! Thanks for the reply, I did however find a redirect which is only adding it to URLs without extensions:
http://www.paulund.co.uk/using-htaccess-to-force-trailing-slash

Comment: Ah, yeah, Magento does that by default. There's lots of great SEO/usability reasons to change that behavior of Magento's, if you can.

Comment: This answer also worked wonders for me. Only problem I ran into was my redirect pointing to a weird server path. I fixed this by adding `RewriteBase /`. This made the redirect work like a charm!

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks!
When trying this or any solution, remember to clear your borwser's cache.

Answer (score 7):

While [Death's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7781331/1453062) works it can be annoying when you forget to add certain file types to the list. You can do this to force trailing slash for all URLs that do not point directly to a file using `!-f` in the condition.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I tried this, but it is adding a trailing slash on files that end in .html

Comment: I tried this as well, but still see trailing slashes added to pages like sitemap.xml. Is it possible that the server settings decide what is viewed as a file to be downloaded and one to be rendered in the browser, and this affects how `!-f` is interpreted?

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. This did, from [SEOMoz](http://moz.com/blog/htaccess-file-snippets-for-seos):

```
# Ensure all URLs have a trailing slash.
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Note the `RewriteBase /` for each rule. At least, when I removed it, it stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

This is working perfectly for me. ( from comment of user Ajax ) 
The problem with other links was my CSS stopped working after applying the redirect rule but CSS is also working fine with the below rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^((.*)[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Complete code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    #Force Trailing slash
    RewriteRule ^((.*)[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)[^/]$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

This should work pretty well. It just checks to make sure the trailing character isn't a slash and adds one.

Comment: This solution adds a slash to files as well!

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me and doesn't rely on evaluating to an actual file as some have suggested the '-f' flag:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-z0-9]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Above examples didn't work for me thanks to forced slash on the end of rule, e.g. $1$2/ .

For me worked this (I used it for wordpress and redirecting to HTTPS). You have to add the condition and rule lines just behind RewriteEngine and RewriteBase lines:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# I added these two lines for redirect to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress`
```

Answer (score 0):

To force the trailing slash, you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R]
```

Note `mod-dir` module that runs before the `mod-rewrite` automatically adds a trailing slash when it sees a request for an `existant dir` ,so we have to exclude directories from the rule otherwise using the rule without `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` on some servers, you will end up at `/dir//` or it can cause problems if you have turned off the directorySlash .

The rule above adds a trailing slash to all requests including files with extension, if you dont want your files with a trailing slash, you can exclude them by adding the following condition above the Rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^.]+)/$" />
```

add this rule in your config file and it is working for me

Comment: <rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([^.]+)/$" />

Comment: You should add the line of code to your answer instead of commenting it !