# Clean and SEO Friendly URL with HTACCESS file

Tags: .htaccess, url, seo, expression

Now i use this code for my website.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This code convert all url of my website:

www.example.com/category/work.php

in

www.example.com/category/work

It's great, but my goal is:

www.example.com/category/work.php

in

www.example.com/category/work/

I need "/" at the end.

Is possibile? This is a typical feature of CMS.

I want it in my site built by me.

Comment: "this code does X, and my goal is X" - so it already works? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: 2nd example have "/"

Comment: then you should output that `/` when you generate the page. your rewrite rules don't do anything to affect the client. they're purely an in-apache rewrite.

Comment: "then you should output that / when you generate the page" how?

Comment: no idea, since you haven't explained anything about your cms. but if you want a browser to display a url a certain way, you have to tell the browser about that. that means outputting `<a href="/category/work/">` when you build the page. just because you have a .htaccess on your server doesn't mean the browser will KNOW what's in the. htaccess and convert a `<a href="/category/work.php">` for you. that's just not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force trailing slash

```
RewriteRule ^((.*)[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Also check this [Stackover answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7781331/1403398)