# Why are my URLs not being rewritten with an ending slash?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

When I enter a URL in my browsers address bar in the form https://myurl.com/path, I'd like the rewrite to be https://myurl.com/path/

In .htaccess, my rewrite rules as as follows:

```
#RewriteEngine On 
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^myurl.com$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://myurl.com/$1 [R,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://myurl.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been doing quite a bit of research into this the last couple days. It looks like you're close. Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [R=301,L]
```

The RewriteCond will check to make sure there's no files with that name, and if not, perform the RewriteRule. More future-proof than having a manual list of extensions!

This is a copy/paste from the following question and answer: I'm not that great with .htaccess but like I said, I've been doing a lot of research on it the last few days.
[.htaccess Rewrite to Force Trailing Slash at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780859/htaccess-rewrite-to-force-trailing-slash-at-the-end)

The [R=301] will also add a 301 redirect to the url for search engines, so they know to look at the slashed version of the page in the future - this helps reduce duplicate content and consolidate analytic information.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @MrMr that worked :) I didn't personally add the rules to this .htaccess file, someone else did, so I can't take credit for being close to the solution.. I'm not sure why the .html rule was added, all pages are in the form https://myurl/path/page/. Are you suggesting that I replace the following lines:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f` and
`RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]` only ?

Comment: The one problem I'm now experiencing is my XML sitemap is now getting a trailing slash, i.e., /sitemap.xml/. Interestingly--and thankfully--pdf files aren't getting a trailing slash.