# add slashes at end of my domain using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

My domin name is http://www.domain1.dk

I want to do to add slashes at end of my domain using .htaccess. Its should come like  http://www.domain1.dk/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Next time please use Google instead of asking this fast.

Answer source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7781331/6486232

In .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```