# The .htaccess file behaves strange when redirecting and if there is a folder in the url path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an `app` folder and a `public` folder. In the public folder is my .htaccess that look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /public
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem I have, is when I call the url on: `http://localhost/public/images` without a trailing slash and the images folder already exists. The results looks like this after I enter the address: `http://localhost/public/images/?url=images`.

But in the other hand, if I add a slash in the end like this: `http://localhost/public/images/` it will remain like this when I enter. So specifically, it only works when I write a slash at the end.

This issue only occurs if there is a folder on that search address.
Someone who has a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to treat `http://localhost/public/images` as `http://localhost/public/images/`, you should enforce a trailing slash.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

See also: [.htaccess Rewrite to Force Trailing Slash at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780859/htaccess-rewrite-to-force-trailing-slash-at-the-end)

Comment: I tested it, but it made strange strings, then I tested again with incognito and it worked. Thanks for the help.